# How to handle Bootstrap tab panel using get parameters or routes in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

I am using a tab panel of bootstrap for account settings. See the image below..[image]

The link of settings is localhost/settings .. I need to access a particular tab. There are two options: one is to use get parameters  like localhost/settings?tab=deactivation and second is to use urls like localhost/settings/deactivation which is defined as localhost/settings/{tab} in route.php.. Which method is best?

The problem with 2nd one is that when ever I change the tab, the URL remains the same. i.e. by changing tab from Deactivation to Password will not result in making url localhost/settings/password instead it will remain the same localhost/settings/deactivation. In case of form validation failure it will move to Deactivation tab.  What is the solution of this problem?

Form validation failure also causes a problem with get parameters in 1st case. How can I solve this problem?

Is there any other better approach to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I remember being able to do it by using anchor tags like `localhost/settings#deactivation`.

If you went the variable route, your could specify the tab like `localhost/settings?tab=deactivation`, and then pass that into the view, and give that tab the 'active' class depending on the value.

I personally wouldn't use routing to set the active tab, seems like overkill.